# Node.js typerror cannot set property of undefined

Tags: node.js, typeerror

I get this error when running my code.

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'variableName' of undefined
```

My Code block is.

```
static setOnline(stream) {
    this.Streams[stream.name] = stream;

    this.updateStreams();
}
```

The line error is this line

```
this.Streams[stream.name] = stream;
```

After googling I think its not setting my array properly. Any help would be great!

EDIT:

```
class Streams {

static setOnline(exampleStreamName) {
    this.streams[exampleStreamName.name] = stream;

    this.updateStreams();
  }
}
```

exampleStreamName is an external string inside of a .json file.

Comment: You haven't posted quite enough code for the problem to be determinable, but it's possible that you need to remove the `static` if you want `this` to refer to the instantiated object. Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I cannot post a minimal example due to using multiple files and another class. I could dm you a hastebin maybe?  Also if I remove the static type I can't use it outside of my class.

Comment: If the problem is spread over multiple files, then combine their essential functionality into one and then post it here, ideally in a live snippet. Without such an example, this question will be closed for being off-topic

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm not saying the code is wrong in multiple places, I'm saying that the snippet uses code from across multiple files. combing them would be around 1000+ lines. I'm sorry I'm new to stackoverflow so idk how to post correctly. I can try to add stuff that will help.

Comment: Read the [ask] page. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.*

Comment: @CertainPerformance Updated my code let me know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Static functions do not have a 'this' member.  That's what makes them static.  This pattern is a 'singleton', as you are using only one instance or class.

```js
class Streams {

  static setOnline(exampleStream) {
    Streams.streams[exampleStream.name] = exampleStream;
    Streams.updateStreams();
  }

  static updateStreams() {
    console.log(Streams.streams);
  }
}

Streams.streams = {}

Streams.setOnline({
  name: 'foo'
})
Streams.setOnline({
  name: 'bar'
})
```

More musings...

It's more flexible to put the streams object inside the Streams class and create one you use everywhere.

It's also confusing to have a static streams member that is not a Streams instance.